# Discriminating documents by scope. The relationship for Documents-Categories-Departments

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

### Discriminating documents by categories

A part of the application I'm working on allows users to upload / browse files (*.pdf, *.jpg, *.docx ...). Uploaded files are stored under a given **Category** and are represented by a **Document** entity.

**Documents** — **Categories** is **1**:**1**

**Categories** — **Categories** is **1**:**M**

[The corresponding DDL](https://gist.github.com/happygrizzly/de284e67585afca43d78184ee9e694e9)

Consider, for example, such a hierarchy of categories (**global documents**):

- **`Normative documents`** (**the root in the categories tree**)

  - Factory standards

    - Standards
    - Technical conditions
  - Regional standards
- **`Reports`** (**the root in the categories tree**)

  - Stats (monthly)
  - Stats (by product type)

### Discriminating documents by scopes / departments

Additionally we discriminate documents as **global documents** (*factory scope*) and **departments documents**.

Each **Department** 'has' a set of documents categories (which is almost the same for all departments):

- **`Guides`** (**the root in the categories tree**)
- **`Reports`** (**the root in the categories tree**)

  - Stats (monthly)
  - Stats (by product type)

### The problem

I can't seem to figure out the relationship(s) for **Documents** — **Categories** — **Departments** when presented with documents scopes:

1. We can say that documents with department_id == 0 are of *global scope*
2. Documents with department_id != 0 relate to some *department scope*
3. Then we need to introduce a **Departments_Categories** table / relationship, because departments can have different sets of documents categories.
4. Then we can navigate documents by **category_id** and **department_id**.

But **departments_categories** relationship seems odd. Is my solution bad? How can I model the relationship?

Comment: Wouldn't you want Department_Documents?

Comment: @nerdlyist Then use two join tables?

Comment: You might also look at a nested set model for your categories tree.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm using AL + closure table technique.

Comment: 1. Please cut and paste code inline formatted as code. 2. A table holds rows that make some statement template (*predicate*) into a true statement. "document *id* has title *title* and category *category* and ...". "document *id* is of global scope". "document *id* has departmental scope *id_department*". What is the predicate of the relationship involving departments & categories and what is "odd" about it?

Comment: @philipxy we could read it as "Department with *id* sees/allowed to have such document Category *id*" regarding the departments_categories relationship. Well, "documents with categories" sounds more simple and natural: an object + its type, than "documents with (categories via departments constraint)". Departments shoudn't know about document categories explicitly. "Documents that belong to departments" seems more connected. But I have to build navigation for each department based on document categories it may have.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't there are likely to be many Documents for a given Category?  If so, that would be Many:1.  Many:1 is implemented by an extra column in one of the tables -- a `category_id` in the Documents table.

Many:Many needs an extra table.  [*Specific recommendations*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

You want your Categories to be in a hierarchy.  This will be something of a challenge because there are no MySQL tools for traversing such.  It will probably be best to use PHP code for dealing with that.

A Report (such as monthly stats) is usually a program that runs to produce information from the database; it is not necessarily a "Document", much less a "Category".  So I don't understand why you mention Reports and Categories in the same sentence.  If a Report is not computed from data, then it is just another Document, and should not be treated differently.